# Request to a json resource from an http page to an https server

Tags: javascript, jquery, https, jsonp

Can a jsonp request from a user on an http page (made by the browser) to an https server be considered secure?

For example:

The user is on:

http://www.example.net

On that page there's a form that, on submit, is sends a jsonp request to:

https://secureapi.net

Can the information on the submit form be read as if the api server is on http?

Comment: I believe you can only do this if you are making the request on the same domain. Otherwise, it wont work.

Comment: @bsimic — Getting around the same origin policy is the *point* of JSONP.

Comment: @Quentin -- Yes, but I don't think it's meant for HTTPS.

Comment: @bsimic — SSL and the Same Origin Policy are defences against completely different types of attack. Nothing about SSL would prevent JSONP from working.

Comment: @Quentin is right https://graph.facebook.com/cocacola can be accessed from an http page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. While the data can't be sniffed in-flight, the HTTP page triggering the request is vulnerable to alteration by man-in-the-middle attacks. JS could be injected which can then leak the data retrieved via HTTPS.

Answer (score 0):

ys it is secure provided U send encrypted data to other page and decrypt the info on another page

Comment: I've having trouble understanding that sentence, but I'm pretty certain that its incorrect.